# How to prove that $\mathfrak d_{KL/L}$ divides $\mathfrak d_{K/F}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be an algebraic number field and $K,L$ its finite extensions contained in an algebraic closure of $F$. Denote the relative different by $\mathfrak d$. I want to prove that $\mathfrak d_{KL/L}$ divides $\mathfrak d_{K/F}$.

Since
$$\mathfrak d_{KL/F}=\mathfrak d_{KL/L}\mathfrak d_{L/F}=\mathfrak d_{KL/K}\mathfrak d_{K/F},$$
it suffices to prove that $\mathfrak d_{L/F}$ is divisible by $\mathfrak d_{KL/K}$.
Write
$$\mathfrak d_{L/F}=\mathfrak d_{L/L\cap K}\mathfrak d_{L\cap K/F},$$
I guess that $\mathfrak d_{L/L\cap K}$ should be divisible by $\mathfrak d_{KL/K}$, but I can't prove it. Any ideas or alternative solutions? Merci beaucoup.